# Javascript and Regex remove text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a ul with a lot of li each with a  child, like that:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Belts (2)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tenis (92)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">T-Shirts (368)</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to remove the parentheses and the numbers inside, but let the rest, i.e:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Belts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tenis</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to do it with jquery and regular expression? I have no idea! :(

Answer (score 3):

```
$("ul li a").html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/\(\d*\)/, "");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/JVVvQ/

Comment: + for first with demo. Although you were missing the trailing space.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary That doesn't make much sense though :)

Comment: well it's the requirement.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Well, if serious, the requirement is *to remove the parentheses and the numbers inside*, but nothing about the space before.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').text(function (_, v) {
    return v.replace(/ \(\d+\)$/, '');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/63H2T/