# How to remove part of a string using jquery?

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I need to remove part of a string using **jQuery** in this way:

I have this string:

```
url(http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/11_CAT_CONILLS_-w900-h600-150x150.jpg)
```

Remove all before the last "/" which is (this part can take other value):

```
url(http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/
```

Remove:

```
)
```

To just leave:

```
11_CAT_CONILLS_-w900-h600-150x150.jpg
```

Comment: Why jQuery? What have you tried?

Comment: My question is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202175/javascript-and-regex-remove-text and see no downvotes on it.

Comment: That's because years ago SO was far more tolerant of questions that showed no effort or code attempts to solve issue at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following to get the desired string

```
var str = "url(http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/11_CAT_CONILLS_-w900-h600-150x150.jpg)";

alert(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).replace(')', ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a mix of `IndexOf` and `substring`. It gets the length of the var you want to keep and remove all before. Then just replace the last or use another method to remove the last char.

```js
var str = "url(http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/11_CAT_CONILLS_-w900-h600-150x150.jpg)";

var returnstr = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)

returnstr = returnstr.substring(-returnstr.length, returnstr.lastIndexOf(")"))

console.log(returnstr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry but not what I need. The part of the  string to leave: '11_CAT_CONILLS_-w900-h600-150x150.jpg' and the part to remove: 'url(http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/' can take other values.

Comment: The rule is to Remove all before the last "/"  and the last ")".

Comment: So you want to remove everything between the last "/" and last ")"?

Comment: no, I need to remove all before the last "/"

Comment: and then just the last ")".

Comment: Please write the exact part of the string you want. it getting confusing

Comment: This is the string: url(http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/11_CAT_CONILLS_-w900-h600-150x150.jpg)

Comment: I need to remove all before the last "/" which is 'url(http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/'

Comment: try look at the example now

Comment: Please tell me if you get it?

Comment: Did you try below solution?

Comment: @JPashs I had the below example 5 min ago, then you said it was still not what you wanted. You also say you have to remove the **LAST** `)` the example below removes all `)`